# Customize block form in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

can I customize widget name for Form in symfony ? I want to customize a widget in Twig, but my form is called in others entity and this name is always changed ...

**Exemple :**

- I have three entity

  - A
  - B
  - C
- I have two forms :

  - A, **call C** *( $builder->add( CTYpe ) )*
  - B, **call C** *( $builder->add( CTYpe ) )*

**But I want to customize C block** in twig.

In **A** form page, widget name is " {% block A_C_widget %} " and in **B** form page, widget name is " {% block B_C_widget %} ".

I want a same name, it's possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that:

```
// ...
$builder->add('name',  CTYpe::class, array(
    'block_name' => 'your_desire_name_here',
));
```

So, when rendering, it will be called `your_desire_name_here_widget`

Comment: Thanks but if y rename with "block_name", the parent name automatically added. Exemple : A_your_desire_name_here_widget and B_your_desire_name_here :/

Comment: Of course, you can also use it in parents element or call `getBlockPrefix()` on form class to set your preferred name on it.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want rename all parents names, it's "poor" ... :/ ... and getBlockPrefix() is not exist in Symfony 2.7 :/

Comment: In 2.7 should be `getName()`

Comment: Sorry but I think you don't understand my problem. I just want a same name widget when I added a form in others forms, for Twig customization :)